# Websocket from UI connecting to one of the instances for Spring boot application for streaming the data coming on a queue

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, jms

I have an UI application (displays streaming) which makes a WebSocket connection to the Spring Boot microservice (multiple JVM'S) and this service forwards the request to one of the upstream servers and listens to the responses on a JMS queue coming from upstream server, which then response messages had to be returned to the socket.

Issue we are facing is since the socket is point to point, and the Spring Boot application is running on multiple instances which all are listening to the same JMS queue we are unable to serve the data back to the WebSocket when a message is received on a instance which the request to upstream wasn't made.

Here's the basic flow:

```
WebSocket -> instance1, instance2, instance3 -> Data provider
```

- Instance1 made the request to data provider.
- Data provider sends the data back to the queue
- Instance 3 receives the message, *but* it doesn't have the socket connection to send the data back.

We had an interim solution using correlation id in JMS headers and selectors on the queue however now the data publisher is not able to provide the correlation id to depend on.

Does anybody have a better suggestion to address this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a request/reply pattern with JMS you must either use a correlation ID **or** a unique temporary queue for the response.

You indicated that, "the data publisher is not able to provide the correlation id to depend on." However, *your* application actually provides the correlation ID. The "data provider" in this case just needs to take it from the message it receives and put it into the response message. The process only requires 2 method calls by the "data provider" - [`javax.jms.Message.getJMSCorrelationID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#getJMSCorrelationID--) and [`javax.jms.Message.setJMSCorrelationID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSCorrelationID-java.lang.String-).

If the "data provider" can't do this then it's doubtful they will be able to accomplish the other option of using a unique temporary queue for the response. However, it's worth explaining in any case. When one of your "instance" servers sends the request message it first needs to use [`javax.jms.Session.createTemporaryQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html#createTemporaryQueue--) to create a temporary queue and then take the return parameter of that method and set it on the request message using [`javax.jms.Message.setJMSReplyTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSReplyTo-javax.jms.Destination-). When the "data provider" receives the message they will get this value using [`javax.jms.Message.getJMSReplyTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#getJMSReplyTo--) and then send the response to this queue where the "instance" will then retrieve it.

These are the two generally accepted ways to implement a request/response pattern with JMS. I don't know of any other ways to implement such a pattern.